# Maven assembly: useStrictFiltering not available for fileSets?

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

To quote the doc:

> useStrictFiltering is a flag that tells the assembly plugin to track each include/exclude pattern to make sure it's used during creation of the assembly

And this says that it is available for `fileSets`: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/advanced-descriptor-topics.html

However the xsd disageees - dependencySets have `useStrictFiltering`, but not `fileSets`: http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd

Maven indeed grumbles if I try and use `useStrictFiltering`, but I need the functionality of `useStrictFiltering` on `fileSets` otherwise parts of my assembly could be missed out without me knowing.

Am I missing something, or is this rudimentary functionality simply missing?

Thanks

Comment: so what exactly is now your problem ? A Bug in the documentation? If yes please [fill in a JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY)

Comment: Hi - the problem is I can't get `useStrictFiltering` on `fileSets` to work.  There potentially is a bug in the doc, but maybe I'm simply doing something wrong. (Edited question to clarify).

Comment: The question is what you like to achieve?

Comment: "to track each include/exclude pattern to make sure it's used during creation of the assembly" for `fileSets`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it simply is not supported:

http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Created-MASSEMBLY-488-useStrictFiltering-in-a-fileSet-in-the-assembly-descriptor-doesn-t-work-td509795.html

Comment: Updated link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-488.  In this JIRA, John Casey just made using useStrictFiltering flag on fileSets produce a clear maven error.  So useStrictFiltering still isn't supported as of maven 3.6.0 and maven-assembly-plugin:3.0.0.